# C# & wpf - Unexpected behavior of (OneWay-Mode) chain-binding between ListBox-Label-ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, two-way-binding

I have the following strange (for me) situation
A ListBox is bound (as Source) to a Label with OneWay Mode, i.e. ListBox is read-only.
The Label is then bound to a ComboBox with TwoWay binding

```
ListBox --> Label <--> ComboBox - arrows denote binding mode
```

The strange thing is that when the program starts and the user selects through the list in the ListBox, all 3 controls behave as expected.
But as soon as one index is chosen from Combobox, the Label continues to work properly (is updated by the Combo), but the OneWay binding to ListBox disappears (is null) and the ListBox cannot update the Label any more.

It seems to me that when Label Content is set by other means besides the OneWay binding (as here with the Combo updating or maybe with a ValueConverter), this binding is cleared by WPF.

The other strange behavior is that if this OneWay binding between ListBox and Label is turned into a TwoWay one, then everything works perfectly.

**The question is** what am I doing wrong, or if this is the normal behavior, where could I find relevant documentation.

Please find below simplified code and XAML demonstrating the case.
My workaround is to set the Label Content with code in ListBox_SelectionChanged.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace Test_Chained_controls
{
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
   {
      public class ComboItems
      {
         public int iDX { get; set; }
         public string sDesc { get; set; }

         public ComboItems(int a, string b)
         {
            iDX = a;
            sDesc = b;
         }
      }

      public class ListItems
      {
         public int iLDX { get; set; }
         public ListItems(int a)
         {
            iLDX = a;
         }
      }

      public List<ListItems> intList = new List<ListItems>();
      public List<ComboItems> idx_StrList = new List<ComboItems>();

      public MainWindow()
      {
         InitializeComponent();

         intList.Add(new ListItems(0));
         intList.Add(new ListItems(1));
         intList.Add(new ListItems(2));
         intList.Add(new ListItems(3));

         idx_StrList.Add(new ComboItems(0, "Zero"));
         idx_StrList.Add(new ComboItems(1, "One"));
         idx_StrList.Add(new ComboItems(2, "Two"));
         idx_StrList.Add(new ComboItems(3, "Three"));
      }

      private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {
         listBox.ItemsSource = intList;
         comboBox.ItemsSource = idx_StrList;
      }

      private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
      {
         //// Set Label Content in case of OneWay
         // var binding = BindingOperations.GetBinding(label, Label.ContentProperty);
         // if (binding != null)
         // {
         //    if (binding.Mode == BindingMode.OneWay)
         //       {}  // Binding set - do nothing
         // }
         // else label.Content = listBox.SelectedItem;
      }
   }
}
```

XAML

```
<Window ... normal stuff
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test_Chained_controls"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="182" Width="500" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="140"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Content="ListBox"    Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="20,10,0,0" />
        <Label Content="Label"      Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="20,10,0,0" />
        <Label Content="ComboBox"   Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Margin="20,10,0,0" />

        <ListBox x:Name="listBox"   Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0"  
                 DisplayMemberPath="iLDX" 
                 SelectedIndex="0"
                 IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
                 SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged"/>

        <Border BorderThickness="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Height="30" 
                Margin="20,20,0,0" BorderBrush="#FFACACAC"  >

            <!-- *********** Label with Mode=OneWay or TwoWay *********** -->
            <Label x:Name="label" Width="100" Height="25"
                   Content="{Binding ElementName=listBox, 
                             Path=SelectedItem.iLDX, Mode=OneWay }" />
        </Border>

        <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" 
                                   Height="30" Margin="20,20,0,0"  

                  DisplayMemberPath="sDesc" 
                  SelectedValue="{Binding ElementName=label, Path=Content, 
                  TargetNullValue=0, FallbackValue=0, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  SelectedValuePath="iDX"  />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**EDIT**

Relevant documentation: [Dependency properties overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/hh700353(v=win.10))

> **Local value:** A local value might be set through the convenience of the property wrapper, which also equates to setting as an attribute or property element in XAML, or by a call to the **SetValue** method using a property of a specific instance. If you set a local value by using a binding or a static resource, these each act in the precedence as if a local value was set, **and bindings or resource references are erased if a new local value is set.**

and further down

> If you set another local value for a property that originally held a Binding value, **you will overwrite the binding entirely, not just the binding's run-time value.**

As I understand, there was some kind of bug related to this case, fixed with the introduction of DependencyObject.**SetCurrentValue**   [The Control Local Values Bug Solution](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vinsibal/2009/05/21/the-control-local-values-bug-solution-and-new-wpf-4-0-related-apis/)

```
public void SetCurrentValue (System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, object value);
// Sets the value of a dependency property without changing its value source.
```

It seems to me that Combobox TwoWay binding is still using **SetValue**, and that's why the binding for (label) gets erased when my (combobox) is used.

To overcome this, I changed the TwoWay binding of (comboBox) to OneWay, and entered the following in the comboBox_DropDownClosed event (showing the currently selected Item), in order to update (label) by code without erasing the existing binding

```
  private void comboBox_DropDownClosed(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
  {
     Binding binding = BindingOperations.GetBinding(label, Label.ContentProperty);
     if (binding != null)
     {
        ComboItems ComboItem = comboBox.SelectedItem as ComboItems;
        int iDX = ComboItem.iDX;

        // Set label value without affecting existing binding
        label.SetCurrentValue(Label.ContentProperty, iDX);
     }
  }
```

With the use of **SetCurrentValue**, code works now as originally intended by "simulating" the TwoWay mode.

Comment: To avoid confusion like this, bind all controls to a common view model. As a note, instead of binding the Label's Content to `SelectedItem.iLDX` it might be simpler to bind to `SelectedValue`, and set `SelectedValuePath="iLDX"` on the ListBox, just like you did on the Combobox.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The code shown here is just for demostration purposes to present the case. My real ListBox has 15+ fields with other similar indexes, so the SelectedValuePath cannot be applied there. 
You are right though, I had a confusing statement within the commented-out code, which is now corrected.
Nevertheless, the problem is still there.

Comment: @Clemens had very good advice. Don't do the binding between the controls, only to the ViewModel. That way it always work as you expect, even if you don't kwno the details of binding framework

Comment: I am sorry but am not using any ViewModel and don't intend to. Am coding for hobby & for entertainment, and in the old-fashioned way. At the same time, I expect the basic language functions to work properly, without going to Paris via North Pole :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing strange at all. Data binding is designed to work this way. When you assign a binding to a dependency property, it means you change the local value of this dependency property to a binding expression. And any update provide by the binding source will be the effective value of this dependency property. If the binding is working in one way mode, any update to this dependency property from other then binding source, will overwrite the local value, result in losing the binding. On the other side, becuase two mode is suppose to update the binding source, dependency object will count any non-expression value as effective value, binding will keep working until you replace or clear it.

- `DependencyObject.GetValue` gets the effective value.
- `DependencyObject.ReadLocalValue` gets the local value.
- `DependencyObject.SetValue` sets the local value.
- `DependencyObject.SetCurrentValue` sets the effective value.
- `DependencyObject.ClearValue` clears the local value.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please provide a link, where this behavior is documented, as originally asked ?
I am asking because, for example, when binding 2 TextBoxes in OneWay mode and the second textbox (the target, setting the binding) is updated manually, the binding continues to function normally, 
i.e. all text entered in the first (source) textbox is shown in the second through the binding, even if the second's Text is independently modified by hand. 
But when this second Textbox.Text property is changed by code, then the binding is cleared, so the behavior is not consistent.

Comment: @john_m Actually, there isn't any official document I know. But you could dig up this fact from the source code of `DependencyObject.SetValue` https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/Windows/DependencyObject.cs,76dfd12a4655a37a. And editing a `TextBox` would replace the binding expression is because if text was changed by editing, instead of  calling `SetValue`, `TextBox` call `SetCurrentDeferredVaule` which will not replace local value for better performance.  This is also can be found in the source code of `TextBox.OnTextContainerChanged`.

Comment: I found some documentation (pls see my EDIT). There was in fact some kind of bug, which in my opinion is not yet completely solved, with the Two-way binding erasing existing bindings. In any case, your mentioning of SetCurrentValue helped me in solving the problem.

Comment: I think that early version of wpf didn't provide an api to set effective value it's more like a design miss than a bug. Since in most situations, we want to get the effective value and set the local value, there's nothing wrong about the implement of `GetValue` and `SetValue`.

Comment: MS called it a bug, and i'm just using their words. Thanks anyway :)